# I Cannot Load Images From TMDB API

Tags: reactjs, rest, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to **build a HULU Clone**
I have **build header successfully** and
I am **Building a results section** where user can see **images** of movie but when I load images it just does **not load Images**

Technology I am Using
React.Js
Next.js
Tailwind css
TMDB Api

The Error Says - `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`
I assume its an error due to poor request to the TMDB Api

Here is My **request.js**

```
const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;

export default {
  fetchTrending: {
    title: "Trending",
    url: `/trending/all/week?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`,
  },
  fetchTopRated: {
    title: "Top Rated",
    url: `/movie/top_rated?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`,
  },
  fetchActionMovies: {
    title: "Action",
    url: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genres=28`,
  },
  fetchComedyMovies: {
    title: "Comedy",
    url: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genres=35`,
  },
  fetchHorrorMovies: {
    title: "Horror",
    url: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genres=27`,
  },
  fetchRomanceMovies: {
    title: "Romance",
    url: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genres=10749`,
  },
  fetchMystery: {
    title: "Mystery",
    url: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genres=9648`,
  },
  fetchSciFi: {
    title: "Sci Fi",
    url: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genres=878`,
  },
  fetchWestern: {
    title: "Western",
    url: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genres=37`,
  },
  fetchAnimation: {
    title: "Animation",
    url: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genres=16`,
  },
  fetchTV: {
    title: "TV Movie",
    url: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genres=10770`,
  },
};
```

And Here is My index.js

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Nav from "../components/Nav";
import Results from "../components/Results";
import request from "../utils/request";

export default function Home({ results }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>HULU</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <Header />

      <Nav />

      <Results results={results} />
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const genre = context.query.genre;
  const requests = await fetch(
    `https://api.themoviedb.org/3${
      request[genre]?.url || request.fetchTrending.url
    }`
  ).then((res) => res.json());
  return {
    props: {
      results: requests.results,
    },
  };
}
```

and This is where I Load Images in Thumbnail.js

```
      import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

function Thumbnail({ result }) {
  const BASE_URL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/orignal";
  console.log(result);
  return (
    <div>
      <Image
        layout="responsive"
        src={
          `${BASE_URL}${result.backdrop_path || result.poster_path}` ||
          ` ${BASE_URL}${result.poster_path}`
        }
        height={1080}
        width={1920}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Thumbnail;
```

this is what results console logs in Thumbnail.js
[Result Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AVBL.png)

[Error Shown in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqFpI.png)

**Please Tell Me If You Need Any Further Information
Thank You in Advance**

Comment: I would try the following 

1. change the base url and ensure it is the correct one 
2. add an API key to the query params. This might be a requirement, who knows. Make sure you read the documentation.

Comment: I did Check The base URL is correct and i tried to directly substitute my api key but nothing changed

Comment: The console log does not show any errors. As such this question is not reproducible.

Comment: Acutally it does i will edit the question and add the image

Comment: Are you certain that `result` always contains a `backdrop_path` or `poster_path`? It seems that in some cases it's passing `undefined` which is causing the 404s.

Answer (score 0):

The URL that is throwing the error points to `http://localhost:3000` instead of the IMBD URL that you have.

Ensure that your proxy is not prepending `http://localhost:3000` to all HTTP requests

Also ensure that you are not using relative URLS as that will cause `http://localhost:3000` to be prepended to the HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue. Then solve by changing few code in `next.config.js`
file like below

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
  domains:['image.tmdb.org'],
  },
  }
```

instead of `module.exports =nextConfig`